# Python version error while installation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, yum

when I do `yum`,
it says

```
bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python2.62.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

my aws instance details are as given below:

```
Linux ip-72-311-15-127 3.14.27-25.47.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 18:36:15 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`/usr/bin/apt-get` also not available

`/usr/bin/yum` is there so I tried

```
/usr/bin/yum install -u mongodb-org
```

which gives

```
bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python2.62.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 2):

First of you you should locate where is python executable

```
which python
```

This would give you a path like `/usr/bin/python`.

Then you can create a link to it

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.62.7
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess yum depends on python but your system doesn't have it.

try reinstalling yum

$ rpm -V yum

if it doesn't solve the problem, try installing python with rpm

Btw, you probably want python 2.7 not 2.6 these days...